# Using a Network Bridge to provide an Internet Connection

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have the following setup:

- (A) a WiFi enabled 3G/4G Device which is providing connection to the internet
- (B) a Wifi enabled laptop that can connect to the 4G device. (with Windows 7)
- (C) a router which has 4 ports and one "Internet" port
- (D) a desktop computer without Wifi. (Running Windows XP Pro SP3)

I created a bridged connection on the laptop that uses its Wifi Adaptor to connect to 4G Device. I have an Ethernet cable running into router into the Internet network port.

I have the desktop plugged into the routers's Network 1-4 ports.

My problem is that I can access the Internet with the laptop but cannot access the Internet using the desktop.

Was there a setting that I skipped in Windows 7 or XP that I should've hit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Internet connection sharing(which comes with Windows 7)
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing

The good news is that if all else is correct, you simply need to turn it on.

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY! Can't believe I didn't need to go through the bridging. Thanks.

Comment: Gotta love when windows actually includes a useful "extra"